# How to execute Redux dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I have a Next.js app with Redux. Using 3 library:

1. Redux Toolkit
2. React Redux
3. next-redux-wrapper

After first user interaction I would store data in redux, so I call:

```
useAppDispatch(setInvoiceItems(itemsWithSelection2));
```

and it raise an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (react-dom.development.js?61bb:14906)
    at useContext (react.development.js?72d0:1504)
    at useReduxContext (useReduxContext.js?9825:21)
```

This is the whole method inside the function component:

```js
const switchSelection = (key) => {
  let itemsWithSelection2;
  if (itemsWithSelection) {
    itemsWithSelection2 = { ...itemsWithSelection };
  } else {
    itemsWithSelection2 = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.keys(invoiceItemsFiltered)
        .filter((key) => invoiceItems[key].defaultValue != undefined)
        .map((key) => [key, invoiceItems[key].defaultValue])
    );
  }
  itemsWithSelection2[key] = itemsWithSelection2[key] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
  setItemsWithSelection(itemsWithSelection2);
  useAppDispatch(setInvoiceItems(itemsWithSelection2));
};
```

What is wrong in my code?

I store `StartPaymentIn` type in redux. It has a field `invoiceItems`, string number pairs.

```js
import { Action, createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { StartPaymentIn, InvoiceItemData } from "../../sharedDirectory/Types";

const initialState: StartPaymentIn = {
  eventId: "",
  hostName: "",
  lang: "",
  invoiceItems: {},
  formFields: {},
};

const StartPaymentInSlice = createSlice({
  name: "StartPaymentIn",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setInvoiceItems(state, action: PayloadAction<{ InvoiceItemData? }>) {
      state.invoiceItems = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setInvoiceItems } = StartPaymentInSlice.actions;
export default StartPaymentInSlice.reducer;
```

```js
export type StartPaymentIn = {
  invoiceItems?: InvoiceItemDataOnBuyTicket;
};

export type InvoiceItemDataOnBuyTicket = {
  [invoiceItemId: string]: number;
};
```

```js
const InvoiceItemsToDeliver = (props: ProductProps) => {
  let itemsWithSelection2 = useAppSelector((state) => state.invoiceItems);

  if (invoiceItems) {
    if (!itemsWithSelection2) {

      useAppDispatch(setInvoiceItems(invoiceItems2));
    }
    
  }
  const [itemsWithSelection, setItemsWithSelection] = useState<{
    [formFieldId: string]: number;
  }>(itemsWithSelection2);
```

Comment: You're rendering the `useAppDispatch` hook conditionally while React expects the same number of hook calls on every render, thus breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). You'll need to refactor your code so it's called at the top level of the component.

Answer (score 0):

React hook "useAppDispatch" cannot be used inside pure functions. They can only be called inside react component. In your code you are using the useAppDispatch(setInvoiceItems(itemsWithSelection2)); inside a pure function outside of the component.